# Poincare Dual of intersection of analytic varieties

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $V, W$ be two analytic varieties meet transversally in a compact complex manifold, and let $\eta_{V},\eta_W$ be their poincare duals in De Rham Cohomology (this definition come from Griffiths and Harris, since it proved that $\int_{V} d\omega = 0$ for any analytic variety$V$), I wonder whether it is true that $\eta_{V\cap W} = \eta_{V}\wedge\eta_{W}$?

If both $V,W$ are smooth, I know this result is true using Thom Isomorphism, see Bott & Tu, 'Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology', Page 69. However I can't carry the proof to varieties with singular points.

Thank you for any help in advance!

P.S. If possible, can you tell me more reference for intersection of analytic varieties except for the book written by Griffiths and Harris?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the intersection product on homology is dual to the cup product on cohomology. Thus, given homology classes $[V]\in H_p(X)$, $[W]\in H_q(X)$ with Poincaré duals $\eta_V,\eta_W$, then $\eta_{V\cap W}=\eta_V\cup\eta_W$. This is true for singular cohomology, and so it does not depend on the smoothness of $V$ and $W$. See [https://math.berkeley.edu/~hutching/teach/215b-2011/cup.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ehutching/teach/215b-2011/cup.pdf) for more on this.

All of this takes place at the level of (co)homology. When talking about intersecting varieties, one typically works with Chow rings, and I know very little about these so I make no claims that the same result holds true in that more rigid setting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it seems that the main theorem in this note requires V and W to be smooth. How can we see that the intersection variety of V and W has the same homology class with the case that [V], [W] are chosen to be smooth?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The notes are proving something about singular (co)homology which doesn't require the involved subspaces to be smooth.

Comment: It sure looks to me like everything is about submanifolds.

Comment: @QuaereVerum At the beginning of the note, A and B are  both assumed to be oriented smooth submanifolds. And in Lemma 4.1 B is also assumed to be smooth.

Comment: Yes, but it happens at the level of (co)homology so there should be no problems with smoothing singularities and remain within the homology class. Perhaps that is too naive, but I would imagine the result carries over to varieties by that logic.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Hmmm... I still feel this is not rigorous enough, maybe I missed something. I will come back to this problem after some further learning. Finally thanks you a lot for your reply.